# Excel Office 365 VBA - Pivot table - List of fields and filters locked

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, pivot-table, field

I found on the website the answer to my question on how to create a pivot table with VBA and to have the possibility to choose the function "xlDistinctCount" [Creating Pivot Table with Distinct Count using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258768/creating-pivot-table-with-distinct-count-using-vba) by adjusting the code to my need.Indeed, I used Asger's code to create three pivot tables (with three different sources of data) within the same macro and it works very well especially regarding the function "xlDistinctCount but I face one issue:

Regarding the three pivot tables, the two first ones have their list of fields and the filters which are locked while for the one that was created last I have access to them. I made a test by deleting the two last pivot tables and I kept only the first one and the result is that finally I have access to the list of fields and the filters. Why I have access to the list of fields and the filters of the pivot table only when there is no other pivot table which follows ?

Below my code:

```
    Sub KPI()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' First Pivot Table
Dim objSheetWithData As Worksheet
Dim objSheetWithPivot As Worksheet
Dim objListObjectWithData As ListObject
Dim objConnection As WorkbookConnection
Dim objPivotCache As PivotCache
Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
Dim objCubeField As CubeField
Dim objPivotField As PivotField
Set objSheetWithData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LIVRAISON")
Set objSheetWithPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TCD SERVICE LEVEL")
If objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects(1)
Else
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Add( _
                                SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                                Source:=objSheetWithData.Range("LIVRAISON"), _
                                XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
End If
For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If objConnection.Type = xlConnectionTypeWORKSHEET Then objConnection.Delete
Next objConnection
Set objConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2( _
                    Name:="My Connection", _
                    Description:="My Connection Description", _
                    ConnectionString:="WORKSHEET;" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
                    CommandText:=objListObjectWithData.Parent.Name & "!" & objListObjectWithData.Name, _
                    lCmdtype:=XlCmdType.xlCmdExcel, _
                    CreateModelConnection:=True, _
                    ImportRelationships:=False)
Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                    SourceType:=xlExternal, _
                    SourceData:=objConnection)
With objPivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End With
For Each objPivotTable In objSheetWithPivot.PivotTables
    objPivotTable.TableRange2.Clear
Next objPivotTable
Set objPivotTable = objPivotCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                    TableDestination:=objSheetWithPivot.Range("A1"), TableName:="TCD LIVRAISON")
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(7)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "IDH + Designation"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(1).Caption = "IDH + Designation"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(9)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Brand"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(2).Caption = "Brand"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(11)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Market"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(3).Caption = "Market"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(8)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Type of Product"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(4).Caption = "Type of Product"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(10)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Business Unit"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(5).Caption = "Business Unit"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(15)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "100% ?"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(6).Caption = "100% ?"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(14), _
                   Function:=xlAverage, _
                   Caption:="Service Rate")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(1).Caption = "Service Level (%)"
objPivotTable.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(13), _
                   Function:=xlSum, _
                   Caption:="Quantity delivered")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(2).Caption = "Quantity Delivered (PAL)"
objPivotTable.DataFields(2).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(7), _
                   Function:=xlDistinctCount, _
                   Caption:="IDH + Designation")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(3).Caption = "Number of SKUs"
objPivotTable.DataFields(3).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

' Second Pivot Table
Set objSheetWithData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NDR")
Set objSheetWithPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TCD RUPTURE RATE")
If objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects(1)
Else
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Add( _
                                SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                                Source:=objSheetWithData.Range("NDR"), _
                                XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
End If
For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If objConnection.Type = xlConnectionTypeWORKSHEET Then objConnection.Delete
Next objConnection
Set objConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2( _
                    Name:="My Connection", _
                    Description:="My Connection Description", _
                    ConnectionString:="WORKSHEET;" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
                    CommandText:=objListObjectWithData.Parent.Name & "!" & objListObjectWithData.Name, _
                    lCmdtype:=XlCmdType.xlCmdExcel, _
                    CreateModelConnection:=True, _
                    ImportRelationships:=False)
Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                    SourceType:=xlExternal, _
                    SourceData:=objConnection)
With objPivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End With
For Each objPivotTable In objSheetWithPivot.PivotTables
    objPivotTable.TableRange2.Clear
Next objPivotTable
Set objPivotTable = objPivotCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                    TableDestination:=objSheetWithPivot.Range("A1"), TableName:="TCD NDR")
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(6)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "IDH + Designation"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(1).Caption = "IDH + Designation"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(8)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Brand"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(2).Caption = "Brand"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(10)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Market"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(3).Caption = "Market"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(7)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Type of Product"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(4).Caption = "Type of Product"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(9)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Business Unit"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(5).Caption = "Business Unit"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(5), _
                   Function:=xlSum, _
                   Caption:="CPV (OOS) [EUR]")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(1).Caption = "OOS (EUR)"
objPivotTable.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 €"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(4), _
                   Function:=xlSum, _
                   Caption:="(OOS) [CON]")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(2).Caption = "OOS (CON)"
objPivotTable.DataFields(2).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(6), _
                   Function:=xlDistinctCount, _
                   Caption:="IDH + Designation")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(3).Caption = "Number of SKUs"
objPivotTable.DataFields(3).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

' Third Pivot Table
Set objSheetWithData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PRODUCTION")
Set objSheetWithPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TCD VALUE AND VOLUME")
If objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects(1)
Else
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Add( _
                                SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                                Source:=objSheetWithData.Range("PRODUCTION"), _
                                XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
End If
For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If objConnection.Type = xlConnectionTypeWORKSHEET Then objConnection.Delete
Next objConnection
Set objConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2( _
                    Name:="My Connection", _
                    Description:="My Connection Description", _
                    ConnectionString:="WORKSHEET;" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
                    CommandText:=objListObjectWithData.Parent.Name & "!" & objListObjectWithData.Name, _
                    lCmdtype:=XlCmdType.xlCmdExcel, _
                    CreateModelConnection:=True, _
                    ImportRelationships:=False)
Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                    SourceType:=xlExternal, _
                    SourceData:=objConnection)
With objPivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End With
For Each objPivotTable In objSheetWithPivot.PivotTables
    objPivotTable.TableRange2.Clear
Next objPivotTable
Set objPivotTable = objPivotCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                    TableDestination:=objSheetWithPivot.Range("A1"), TableName:="TCD PRODUCTION")
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(9)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "IDH + Designation"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(1).Caption = "IDH + Designation"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(11)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Brand"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(2).Caption = "Brand"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(13)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Market"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(3).Caption = "Market"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(10)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Type of Product"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(4).Caption = "Type of Product"
With objPivotTable.CubeFields(12)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Caption = "Business Unit"
End With
objPivotTable.PageFields(5).Caption = "Business Unit"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(5), _
                   Function:=xlSum, _
                   Caption:="Stock Value")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(1).Caption = "Stock Value (EUR)"
objPivotTable.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 €"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(15), _
                   Function:=xlSum, _
                   Caption:="Amount of PAL")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(2).Caption = "Quantity Produced (PAL)"
objPivotTable.DataFields(2).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
Set objCubeField = objPivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure( _
                   AttributeHierarchy:=objPivotTable.CubeFields(9), _
                   Function:=xlDistinctCount, _
                   Caption:="IDH + Designation")
objPivotTable.AddDataField objCubeField
objPivotTable.DataFields(3).Caption = "Number of SKUs"
objPivotTable.DataFields(3).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: My first recommendation is proper indentation: here's a cool [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to get you started.

Comment: Hello BigBen, thank you for your feedback. I used the indenter (without changing settings) and unfortunately I got the same results. The two first pivot tables have their list of fileds and the filters still locked except the third one which are not followed by another pivot table.

Comment: The indenter won't fix errors, but it will improve readability...

Comment: I put the code after using the indenter.

Comment: Hello, anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps due to overwriting the connection by using the same connection name for each pivot table.  Perhaps changing:
Set objConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2( _
Name:="My Connection", _
to "My Connection 1", "My Connection 2", "My Connection 3"?
(I didn't test this).